# Random Split takes out some audience members

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I put 3100 people into a journey audience. The first step is a 50/50 random split. There seems to be some kind of a filter wich I can´t see, because there arrive only 2599.

Has somebody an idea? Stay healty!
[image]

Comment: The 3.100 people were inserted at the same time in the journey or it is scheduled? Have you checked if there are duplicates in the source Data Extension?

Comment: there are no duplicates in the audience. The insert is made by a sheduled automation and the journey is using that automation as the shedule. I think you know what I am trying ti say :-). The amount is 3100 per run

Comment: What is the entry sets? You can also try to check in the History tab of the journey if you have more information about that specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

Check the send report for each of those emails on the two separate paths. I have found that the numbers shown in the Journey Builder UI is not always accurate. You can also update the contact record with to a field with something “Path 1” and “Path 2” and export that DE to check the numbers.

Also check that those email records are subscribed and have the correct email syntax. List detective may remove email addresses at send time if formatted incorrectly.

My hunch is that it’s the former. I have seen that those numbers shown aren’t always accurate. You’re better off looking at the send reports or updating the DE.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Einsten STO,It's will send EDM when user need time, So the first Path is less than your second path. Only 24h or 48 (depend on your STO Setting),you will find all members entry the STO

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).